# Не получается перевести речь, введённую через микрофон для blenderbot 90M

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-translate, text-to-speech, синтезатор-речи

Всем доброго времени суток)
Уже целый день мучаюсь с переводом вводимого микрофоном текста, но ничего не получается.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

import googletrans

from gtts import gTTS

import transformers

import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
from googletrans import Translator

class ChatBot():
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("--- starting up", name, "---")
        self.name = name

    def speech_to_text(self):
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as mic:
            print("listening...")
            audio = recognizer.listen(mic)
        try:
            self.text=recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language = 'ru-RU')
            translator = Translator()
            result = translator.translate(self.text, src='ru', dest='en')
            print("me --> ", result)
        except:
            print("me -->  ERROR")

    @staticmethod
    def text_to_speech(text):
        print("ai --> ", text)
        speaker = gTTS(text=text, lang="en", slow=False)
        speaker.save("res.mp3")
        os.system("afplay res.mp3")  #mac->afplay | windows->start
        os.remove("res.mp3")

    def wake_up(self, text):
        return True if self.name in text.lower() else False

    @staticmethod
    def action_time():
        return datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    ai = ChatBot(name="miku")
    nlp = transformers.pipeline("conversational", model="facebook/blenderbot_small-90M")
    os.environ["TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM"] = "true"

    while True:
        ai.speech_to_text()

        ## wake up
        if ai.wake_up(ai.text) is True:
            res = "Hello I am Miku the AI, what can I do for you?"
        
        ## action time
        elif "time" in ai.text:
            res = ai.action_time()
        
        elif any(i in ai.text for i in ["thank","thanks"]):
            res = np.random.choice(["you're welcome!","anytime!","no problem!","cool!","I'm here if you need me!","peace out!"])
        
        else:   
            chat = nlp(transformers.Conversation(ai.text), pad_token_id=50256)
            res = str(chat)
            res = res[res.find("bot >> ")+6:].strip()

        ai.text_to_speech(res)
```

Выдает ошибку из кода:

```
except:
            print("me -->  ERROR")
```

Если можно, хотелось бы узнать и то, как можно переводить речь бота.

Comment: Добавьте вывод, какая именно ошибка возникает. В данном случае просто уберите try-except, и посмотрите что именно в консоль выводит.

Comment: В том месте, где падает ошибка: `except (Exception as e):\n print(e)`. Ошибку нам.

Comment: Убрал try и except и выдаёт такую ошибку:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vlad\Desktop\1.py", line 52, in <module>
    ai.speech_to_text()
  File "C:\Users\Vlad\Desktop\1.py", line 24, in speech_to_text
    self.text=recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language = 'ru-RU')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueErro